# Powershell's Invoke-Command not working when called from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, invoke-command

I have a Powershell script, which is working just fine, when called from command line, but only partially fine when executed by the Windows Task Scheduler. The script looks as follows:

```
# Do things, which are always working.
$session = new-pssession -computername SRV
Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock { D:\script.bat }
# Do things, which are always working.
```

The task defined in the Task Scheduler is completed without errors. As you see, all parts before and after `Invoke-Command` are working, also when called by the Task Scheduler. Only the `Invoke-Command` itself is only working when called from the command line.

My only guess is, that the Powershell script is exiting prematurely, but I didn't find any way to confirm this or even solve the issue.

Comment: Is the task running with highest privileges?

Comment: Yes, it is. Additionally, I should add, that it is running using the System user account.

Comment: Don't use LOCAL SYSTEM for this kind of task. Either use NETWORK SERVICE or create a dedicated (domain) account with the required privileges.

Comment: I just changed the user to Network Service. However, I don't see any changes concerning the original problem.

Comment: Have you tried a domain account (for instance your own, as @Jimbo suggested)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is likely to be a permissions issue - as a test, run the task using the same credentials as when it is run at the command line...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with `Invoke-Command` when I called a script from Task Scheduler to run certain scriptblocks on multiple computers. I don't know why, but setting the **"Start in"** folder of the action to the **folder of the script** solved it.
[image: action configuration window]

Comment: This would only solve the issue if OP was using a relative path to batch file eg `Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock { script.bat }` rather than using the full path to the file like they are `Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock { D:\script.bat }`

Comment: I also used pull path to the script (see screenshot) and still invoke-command did not work, only after I set the "Start in" folder. Perhaps any valid "Start in" could work, but I did not test that.

Comment: I mean **"full path"**.